# How to exclude groups of rows based on aggregation results while retaining individual rows for returned results?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im doing a simple data analysis project i BigQuery. There are three columns: ID, date, and TotalMinutesAsleep. If I want to keep the IDs where they have at least 15 days(rows) of data, how would I do that?

I tried something like this but If I don't average the TotalMinutesAsleep column this isnt doable. but I dont want to average, I want to get rid of the distinct Ids with less than 15 rows in this table.

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  date,
  TotalMinutesAsleep
FROM
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily sleep 1`
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to do the counting for the Id:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  date,
  TotalMinutesAsleep
FROM
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily sleep 1` a
WHERE (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily sleep 1` b
       WHERE b.id=a.id) >= 15
```

You could also do this:

```
with Step1 as (
SELECT
  Id,
  date,
  TotalMinutesAsleep,
  count(*) over (partition by Id) as Cnt

FROM
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily sleep 1`
)
select 
  Id,
  date,
  TotalMinutesAsleep
 from Step1
where Cnt >= 15
```

Or, as @Matbailie reminded us, since Bigquery seems to support QUALIFY clause:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  date,
  TotalMinutesAsleep
 
FROM
  `fitbit-data-exploration.FitBit_Tracker.daily sleep 1`
QUALIFY count(*) over (partition by Id) >= 15
```

There are other ways of doing it but these could help.

Comment: Or just use `QUALIFY 15 <= count(*) over (partition by Id)` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Comment: Thanks @Matbailie, I didn't know bigquery supported QUALIFY.

Comment: Then wouldn't you mark as answer? or vote as useful?